# Perform a function for a list of values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to write a program to fetch data from Google Sheets and insert it into MYSQL. I have a list of values and I want to perform a function for each value in the list till the last value.

```
##Get range

def range_list():
    for i in range(1,5):
        print(i)

list = range_list()
```

**##Get values from for list**

```
    array_data = (array(array(data[list])))
    print(array_data)
    
    s_symbol = str((array(array_data[0])))
    s_name = str((array(array_data[1])))
```

I want to change values in **list** and perform the below function

```
    ##Insert to DB
        
      def insert_sql() :
            sql_insert_statement = """INSERT INTO sheet_data ( 
                                symbol,
                                name )
                                VALUES ( %s,%s )"""
            
            val = (s_symbol, s_name)
            
            cur.execute(sql_insert_statement, val)
            mydb.commit()
            print(cur.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into s_user table")
            cur.close()

       insert_sql()
```

What I want to achieve here is that the script should fetch the value from **list** and the function *insert_sql* should be performed. After the process is successful, the value in **list** should change with preceding value. This process should continue till the value in **list**.

So for `array_data = (array(array(data[1])))`

`insert_sql()` should get executed

Again for `array_data = (array(array(data[2])))`
`insert_sql()` should get executed

This process should continue to till the value 5

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I got confused with this (array(array(data[1]))), can you explain what is the input and the schema of it and what do you want as output?
For example you have an array of strings named A, and you want to execute insert_sql for each element of A and have the result in an array named B. (This was just an example, i need some clarification.)

Comment: Input is fetched from Google Sheets and it's displayed as an array list [('APPL, APPLE INC.')], [('AMZN, AMAZON INC.')]  array_data = (array(array(data[1]))) prints [('APPL, APPLE INC.')] And so, s_symbol = str((array(array_data[0]))) prints APPL and s_symbol = str((array(array_data[1]))) prints APPLE INC. Similarly, (array(array(data[2]))) prints [('AMZN, AMAZON INC.')]

Values 1, 2, 3, etc. are are linked to company's symbol and its name. I want values to change in (array(array(data[list]))) and every time the value changes, insert_sql function should also get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you get the data from google sheet well and by you can have data of each index of your array_data list by

```
s_symbol = str((array(array_data[0])))  # It is supposed to have value APPL
s_name = str((array(array_data[1])))  # It is supposed to have value APPLE INC
```

so you just need a for loop on your array_data and modify your insert_sql function a bit, as below:

```
def insert_sql(s_symbol, s_name):
    sql_insert_statement = """INSERT INTO sheet_data ( 
                          symbol,
                          name )
                          VALUES ( %s,%s )"""

    val = (s_symbol, s_name)

    cur.execute(sql_insert_statement, val)
    mydb.commit()
    print(cur.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into s_user table")
    cur.close()
```

and you can run this function for each entry of your list

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    array_data = (array(array(data[i])))  # this is supposed to be like [('APPL, APPLE INC.')]
    s_symbol = str((array(array_data[0])))  # this is supposed to be like APPL
    s_name = str((array(array_data[1])))  # this is supposed to be like APPLE INC.
    insert_sql(s_symbol, s_name)
```

let me know if the are any problems with it.

Comment: Perfect! Worked as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Define another function

```
def do_something(parameter):
    return "This number:" + str(parameter)  # for example

def range_list():
    for i in range(1,5):
        print(do_something(i))  # then call the function

range_list()
```